# Convert linked list to array (pseudo-code)

Tags: arrays, linked-list, pseudocode

I am studying algorithms and an exercise asked me to convert a linked list to an array (using pseudo-code), this is what I have done:

```
convert_LL_array (List, array)
  i = 0
  current = List.start

  while (current != null)    
      array[i] = current->data
      current = current->next
      i++

  return array
```

And here is the answer:

```
convert_LL_array (List, array)
  i = 0
  current = List.start

  while (current->next != null)    
      array[i] = current->data
      current = current->next
      i++

  return array
```

Why should I use "current->next" when I compare to "null"? I think that does not add the last element to the array.

Comment: Who says the second version is correct?  Your code looks fine to me.

Comment: That was the answer I received from the material I'm using.

Comment: That answer won't work correctly for the case of a list with only a head element.  See for yourself: it will return _without_ copying anything merely because the next element is null.

Comment: Yes, that case was very conclusive!! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pseudo-code seems correct,there is nothing wrong with that.As Tim Pointed out that other answer will not work in the case if there is only one element in the linked list.I just want to add that you can check complete code on below link,if you have still have any confusion.
https://ideone.com/qN1HBZ

```
struct ListNode{
    int data;
    struct ListNode* next;
    ListNode(int val):data(val),next(NULL){}
};

void convertLLtoArray(ListNode* head, vector<int>&arr){
    //if there is no element then return
    if(head==NULL)return;
    //crawling pointer
    ListNode* crawl = head;
    //iterate until list pointer become NULL
    while(crawl!=NULL){
        arr.push_back(crawl->data);
        crawl = crawl->next;
    }
    return;
}
```